# SQL While Loop keep running

Tags: sql, while-loop

```
delete from summary
Declare @rows int
set @rows=0


while @rows <29000
begin
    insert into Summary 
    select  * from table a full join table b on 
    ID = ID
    where pk is not null
end
```

I've tried to run the code above but it kept on running without stopping, when I finally stopped it, it gave the following result:

> (28029 row(s) affected)
>
> (28029 row(s) affected)
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 13
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Summary'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Summary'.
> The statement has been terminated.

Then I thought it was the PK issue, so I delete everything from the table and just run the insert statement only with out the while loop, and it works.  So I am guessing something else is wrong, but I have no idea what it is.  Can someone else point it out for me?  And I've verified that there are only 28K+ rows in the table.

Comment: I don't see you ever incrementing `@rows`, so `@rows` is going to always be less than 29000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider updating the @rows variable inside the loop to avoid an infinite loop.

This can be done with

```
SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
```

However, this will still cause the query to execute twice and violate the primary key.  You will need a few more rows to avoid running the query twice.

Since your intent is to limit the rows inserted, I recommend using `TOP` to limit the rows selected instead of the loop.

```
insert into Summary 
select top 29000 * from table a full join table b on ID = ID
where pk is not null
```

Also, I recommend providing an ORDER BY clause in any query with a TOP.  If you don't define the order, the database decides it and the database can decide differently as it likes.

Comment: IF they use @@ROWCOUNT won't it always be 1? Since it is only inserting one record on each iteration?

Comment: @RyanWilson they are inserting 28029 rows, the result of the join.

Comment: If they are doing a bulk insert, then why loop at all?

Comment: But sometime there are more than 29K records and we want to keep at only 29K or less.

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, we would need to know the context of the operation to judge if the solution proposed is any good.  In any event, we know what this code is doing and why it has the output that it does.

Comment: @user3083228 Then do `SELECT TOP 28999`

Comment: @RyanWilson just tried select top 28999, it still same issue, but if I ran it with only the insert statement then it works....I see what u meant now, so select top 29k only and don't do it within the loop.

Comment: @user3083228 You will always have an infinite loop if `@rows` is < 29000, since you did select top 28999, 28999 < 29000 on into infinite